# Amazon S3Storage Denying objects without specified ACL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is my first post so any tips are much appreciated.

I currently have a policy applied to an S3bucket designed to prevent users from uploading an object with a public ACL. When uploading via powershell tools with a specified canned ACL it works:

```
Write-S3Object -bucketname isrmtestbucket -File C:\Users\user\Desktop\DemoFolder\text.txt -CannedACLName private
```

But if I remove the CannedACLName it is denied.

```
Write-S3Object -bucketname isrmtestbucket -File C:\Users\user\Desktop\DemoFolder\text.txt
```

I have read the Amazons documentation, and it indicates that objects are uploaded as "private" by default. Which is included in the Policy.

Here is the ACL:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "DenyPublic",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotLike": {
                "s3:x-amz-acl": [
                    "private",
                    "NoACL",
                    "bucket-owner-full-control",
                    "bucket-owner-read"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

Sidenote: If I try to create a folder in the GUI it is also denied when the policy is applied.

Any guidance would be awesome I am having a bit of a headache with this one.

Here is the policy S3 policy for the user:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: What if you specify -CannedACLName NoACL?

Comment: I tried to specify NoACL and it returned "Access Denied". I would like to ensure users can upload without specifying anything, so it does not effect any existing scripts.

Comment: If these users are public or they are AWS users outside of your AWS account then you do not want them uploading with no ACL. That doesn't equate to "private"; it equates to "they own the object and you cannot view/modify it or its ACL". All you can do in that situation, as bucket owner, is delete the object.

Comment: This policy will be applied to all existing buckets in our environment. Some to which I do not own. When using the command original command without a specified ACL it gets rejected. Although AWS documentations states they are uploaded as "private" by default here:     http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#canned-acl

Comment: The users will only be part of our AWS account.

Comment: Please add to your question the policy for the user that is executing Write-S3Object

Comment: Added per John Hanley

Comment: I was hoping you could use StringNotLikeIfExists in place of StringNotLike for the x-amzn-acl condition but it's not behaving how I would expect it to behave. It is denying a simple put with no ACL, which perhaps suggests that x-amzn-acl is present but does not have a value that I expected. I expected it to be absent, or if present to be "" or "NoACL" (or some variant) but none of those work. Hmm.

Comment: That is the same logic that I used. I tried " ", "","NoACL", and "NULL"

Comment: Do you know of a way we could view the headers sent from the cli?

Comment: aws --debug is available

Comment: --debug did not present the raw headers, just the operation(in powershell tools)

Comment: I'm using the awscli (aws s3 cp). You can see the canonical request.in the debug output and it shows me content-md5;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date. The absence of x-amz-acl in the debug output is evidence that it's *not* being sent. Compare that with an s3 cp with bucket-owner-full-control where you *will* see the x-amz-acl header.

Comment: Would a deny policy with condition StringEquals for s3:x-amz-acl having values public-read or public-read-write suffice?

Comment: I just downloaded the cli tools and am viewing the request to the same result.  The header u'x-amz-acl' is present when an ACL is specified: headers': {u'x-amz-acl': 'private', 'User-Agent':, but no no value of "noACL" is present in unspecified requests: 'headers': {'User-Agent': 'aws-cli/1.11.169 Python/2.7.9 Windows/8 botocore/1.7.27'

Comment: The other approach would suffice. But i am having issues with changes being made in the gui explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47539742/aws-s3-web-console-overriding-bucket-policy

Comment: BTW here is a recent blog post from AWS on a reactive approach to detect and remediate S3 permission issues, in case you choose to implement that at some point. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-detect-and-automatically-remediate-unintended-permissions-in-amazon-s3-object-acls-with-cloudwatch-events/