# AWS S3 Web Console overriding bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Currently I have a policy applied to a test bucket that is designed to prevent users from uploading s3objects with "public-read" and "public-read-write" ACLs.

When I try to upload via command line the requests are successfully blocked with "Access Denied" as expected:

```
Write-S3Object -bucketname testbucket -File C:\Users\user\Desktop\DemoFolder\secret_data.txt -cannedACLName public-read
```

Same result with "public-read-write":

```
Write-S3Object -bucketname testbucket -File C:\Users\user\Desktop\DemoFolder\secret_data.txt -CannedACLName public-read-write
```

But when I access the s3bucket via the Web Console GUI I am able to upload public objects. Along with manipulating an existing "private" object to public via the "make public" button.

Here is the bucket policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "DenyPublic",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "s3:x-amz-acl": [
                    "public-read",
                    "public-read-write"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Also here is the policy for s3 access from the user:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}

I feel like the fix or logic is really simple. I just cannot put my finger on it.

Comment: I believe it can be done using IAM policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what's going on here is that the AWS Console is not triggering your Deny policy, because it's not using canned ACLs. Instead, it's explicitly granting the READ_ACP permission to the AllUsers group (using the x-amz-grant-read header), after uploading the file.

I set up a similar policy and tested the canned ACL approach on PutObject (it failed):

```
$ aws s3 cp myfile s3://B/K --acl public-read
Result: Access Denied
```

Then I tested a non-ACL copy, followed by an ACL update to the object using the canned ACL approach (the upload succeeded, but the ACL update failed):

```
$ aws s3 cp myfile s3://B/K
Result: OK

$ aws s3api put-object-acl --bucket B --key K --acl public-read
Result: Access Denied
```

Then I tried the grant approach with the AllUsers group (it succeeded):

```
$ aws s3 cp myfile s3://B/K
Result: OK

$ aws s3api put-object-acl --bucket B --key K --grant-read uri=http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers
Result: OK
```

The last two tests attempt to do the same thing (upload an object and make it world-readable) but they do it in different ways and one is denied by your policy while the other is not.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. The READ_ACP permission did not cross my mind. Thank You!